# cloning a repo with os.exec("git", "clone")

Tags: go

Running the code below, I expected the github hosted project `username/mysuperrepo` to be cloned (once I visit the `clone`  path) into the repo where this go project is running, but it doesn't work. After stopping the application, there's no directory for `mysuperrepo` no any of the files that I would expect from running `git clone https://github.com/username/mysuperrepo.git` from the command line

Question: Why wouldn't the code below produce a clone of the repo in the directory where the go program is running?

```
func clone(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
  var repo = "https://github.com/username/mysuperrepo.git"
  exec.Command("git", "clone", repo)
  w.Write([]byte(repo))
}
func main(){
  http.HandleFunc("/clone/", clone)
  log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

Comment: check every `error` returned.

Comment: @JiangYD exec.Command doesn't return an error, it reutrns a *Cmd

Comment: o, maybe I have to call `Run` on the command! (and Run returns an error)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to call `Run` to actually execute the command.

```
cmd := exec.Command("git", "clone", repo)
err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    // something went wrong
}
```

Comment: This will clone the repo in my project dir, what if i wanted to copy the repo to another dir, how would i go about this?

Comment: @JCastillo: a bit late, but you can set `cmd.Dir = "path/to/desired/dir"` before you run it.